# Is there a Sharepoint API to get nested directory structure for a particular folder at once within a site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there a Sharepoint API to get entire content of files/folders for a particular folder at once ?
I don't want to use GetFolderByServerRelativePath recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If don't want to use GetFolderByServerRelativePath, you can use CSOM with CAML Query like this:

```
            string password = "pwd";
            string account = "user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            var secret = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                secret.AppendChar(c);
            }
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account,secret);
                Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                ctx.Load(list);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/shared%20documents/");
                ctx.Load(folder);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                     <Query>
                                     </Query>
                                 </View>";
                camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
                ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                ctx.Load(listItems);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var item in listItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString());
                }
            }
```

will return all folders/subfolders/files together, hopefully, this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. Actually I was looking for an API that will simply return the content either in nested or flat format.
I want to avoid recursion if possible.

Comment: Use CAML Query camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                     <Query>
                                     </Query>
                                 </View>";

I willl update answer, please check, this won't need to loop subfolders recursively

Comment: @kartiksharma, have you tried to use CAML Query as above ? Did it work for you ?